# Trying to get floating figure references in R-markdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to get floating figure references in R-markdown so I don't have to manually change all the references if I add a figure later on. I know this is possible in R sweave/latex but I am hoping there is a way to do it in markdown because I am much more familiar with it. I included the code below for a simple example so it is clear what I am trying to do. Any help is much appreciated, I have been looking for an answer to this for a while.

````
 \begin{figure}
```{r}
d<- data.frame(x= 1:10,y = 1:10)
plot(d$x,d$y)
```
\caption{\label{fig:graph} plot of x vs y}
\end{figure}
````

In figure \ref{fig:graph} you see a plot of x vs y

Comment: read this one? https://rpubs.com/ajlyons/autonumfigs

Answer (score 1):

The numbering is done automatically, see this example and note the `fig_caption: yes` argument in the YAML header:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
---

```{r, fig.cap="One"}
d<- data.frame(x= 1:10,y = 1:10)
plot(d$x,d$y)
```

```{r, fig.cap="Two"}
d<- data.frame(x= 1:10,y = 1:10)
plot(d$x,d$y)
```
````

Comment: May also try the **bookdown** package: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/a-single-document.html